# How do sulphate esters compare to phosphate esters?

Tags: biochemistry, esters, organosulfur-compounds, organophosphorus-compounds

In particular, the energy released from hydrolysis of the -S-O-S- bonds and how stable are they in aqueous solution compared to phosphate esters?

Comment: I disagree with this being too broad. I'd think a yes with an example or two would suffice.

Comment: Yes. How is it "too broad"? I'm asking for comparison of sulphate esters and phosphate esters when it comes to hydrolysis in aqueous solutions.